# Is it fair to close a question with a bounty attached to it

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question, bounty

This [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33807/issues-with-this-pattern-to-restrict-access-to-private-members/) does not have working code but has a bounty attached, and only needs minor polishing to make the code work.

Should the question be closed or not? The author has been informed since a while ( over 10 days ) that the code does not actually work.

Comment: Putting the question on hold would prevent other people from posting answers, which IMHO isn't fair for the 100pts the OP has paid for the bounty. Perhaps we can vote to close it after the grace period has ended and the bounty was awarded (if it's not fixed by then of course!)?

Comment: @retailcoder: I have just now flagged a moderator.  Hopefully this can be straightened out (by anyone) before the bounty expires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I have found a similar MSO post for reinforcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions).

This is a very good question.  Of course, we cannot stop a user from starting a bounty.  In this case, the OP insists that the code works, but the community thinks otherwise.  Whether or not close votes come in, anyone can still provide an answer, which will very likely be an overall review and not a fix.  The OP could still choose to award the bounty if it's helpful enough, or continue to wait for the type of answer that he/she may not receive on this site.

*Overall, I think it's best to flag a moderator*.  If it is that the code indeed does not work, based on community input and/or personal knowledge, the bounty can be refunded.  Another option before this refunding is getting the community to edit in the fixes, and I've seen this done before (but not on a regular bases).  Now, if there are *a lot* of needed fixes, it may be best for SO.  This would then leave the bounty period to continue to expiration while the post is closed.  Or, the bounty could still be refunded, then started again as soon as the code is fixed.

Comment: how many more edits until this becomes a community wiki question?

Comment: @Malachi: This will be triggered after the OP makes 5 more edits.  Or, if 2 more users (I believe) make an edit.

Comment: @Malachi: However, this isn't related to the bounty.  As they have nothing to do with votes (not even the rep cap), the bounty can still be properly awarded even if the question is already CW.

Comment: I understand that, but the point is, someone could "legally" make the code work before giving the answer making it all "legal"  ,  Right?

Comment: @Malachi: Yes, that should be okay.  If we're able to review code that works, regardless of how it was fixed, then I think that's even better.

Comment: @Jamal that last statement looks like it's opening a door we'd rather not stick our feet into, no?

Comment: @retailcoder: You mean fixing the code with an edit?

Comment: @Jamal Yup. If the OP won't fix their code, fixing it for them would create a precedent. I think the fix should appear in a comment, and if anyone wants to review it they ought to take it into consideration, but the OP's code is for the OP to fix IMHO. And after the bounty is awarded we can close/put on-hold if it's still not fixed.

Comment: I, uh, must have forgotten the part where you mention it's been done before - just re-read your answer... my phone's screen doesn't fit that part + all the comments + the touch qwerty keyboard :) ..I guess that *could* be one of such exceptional cases then.

Comment: There is also a post in [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207851/flag-declined-on-bountied-unclear-question-that-is-very-old-with-no-answers-why/207852#207852) worth checking.